# MPMusicPlayerController volume increase and decreasing dynamically

Tags: ios4

I am implementing a musci application in that I need to support playing of 2 audio files at a time. I did it one with MPMusciplayer controller and another one with AVAudioPlayer as per my requirements I need to support 2 different volume levels for both players at a time when they both playing. Is this possible?

Can you guys please help one this?

Thanks in advance
Chandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Slider View and Give that slider value to this code will help you.

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:slider.value];
```